# Use unicode character U+2192 in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, unicode

I have the following document (excerpts):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Paketimporte
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[markup=nocolor,deletedmarkup=xout]{changes}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207C6}{\dash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2192}{\dash}

\begin{document}    
% Titelblatt
\maketitle
\pagebreak

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\begin{lstlisting}
    foo → bar
\end{lstlisting}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following error when invoking `pdflatex`:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@FillFixed@\lst@EC� (U+207C6)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. foo →
```

I already googled for this error and found some similar, but not equal issues, which encourage to use `\ DeclareUnicodeCharacter` or `\newunicodechar`, but which does not work.
The file in question is also `UTF-8` encoded:

```
$ file -i test.tex
test.tex.tex: text/x-tex; charset=utf-8
```

How can I get latex to display the `→` character?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am terribly sorry.

Comment: U+207C6 points to an undefined point in the CJK Ideograph Extension B block. Are you sure you meant it?

Comment: No, `→` is actually `U+2192 ` but according to the tex error message it recognizes it as `U+207C6`. I have no clue why.

Comment: listings is not designed up for multi-character UTF8 input and so it is confused and the number shown in the error message is entirely spurious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listings` doesn't really have UTF-8 support, so what happens when it finds `→` is essentially random.

You need not to declare the character if you load `textcomp`, because LaTeX knows how to translate it to `\textrightarrow`, but you need to teach it explicitly to `listings`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  literate={→}{\textrightarrow}1
}

\begin{document}

foo → bar

\begin{lstlisting}
foo → bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah. So it's due to a shortcoming in the `listings` package. Tricky.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an output with literate:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Paketimporte
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate={→}{$\rightarrow$}1}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2192}{\dash}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    foo → bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thank you. Now I'm trying to understand why.